# Can a big microwave used to dry clothes?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I was wondering if it is possible for a microwave in principle to dry clothes (assuming of course it is big enough).

Comment: ***Experimentalist answer:*** Grab a fire extinguisher, get your least favorite shirt wet, wring it out and pop it in there...

Answer (score 3):

It's not merely possible, but in fact [microwave dryers are in commercial production in Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clothes_dryer#Microwave_dryers).

However, there are certain [technical issues](http://www.fypower.org/res/tools/products_results.html?id=100144) with [cost and safety](http://www.appliancemagazine.com/editorial.php?article=150&zone=first=1), as commenter @dmckee alluded to above, and I don't see any evidence that they are available generally in the rest of the world.

Comment: The Japanese get *all* the cool gadgets.

Comment: If by "cool" you mean "catches your Levi's on fire", then yeah. :)

Comment: I mean a combined washer-dryer that weighs your clothes when you pop them in (to set the water level automatically) and shuts off just when they're dry without shrinking them; I mean a low drawer freezer with a liner that comes out and doesn't let all your cold air spill on the floor every time you peak in it; and most of all I mean *heated toilet seats*. Do you have any idea how hard those are to buy in the US? And they are *so simple*! Arghhhh!